# Fill Path is automatically lowered in opacity in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, fill

I am having problems filling paths in photoshop (which i was just doing fine yesterday), usually they just fill with a solid color. Now they are being filled with a lowered opacity color and i can see the layers below each one, or they overlap to make darker colors.

I have made sure to check my opacity and transparency settings as well as.

Is there any way to fix this? Surely I pressed a button accidentally to cause this, but I haven't the slightest clue.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i realized it must have lowered in the actual "Fill Path" options, which I dont normally use since I have it set to a shortcut now. Disregard!

Comment: Note that while self-answers are fine, you can also delete your question, if you think that nobody else will benefit from it (your question may be closed as tech support anyway). Should you want the answer to remain, you should accept it however (click on the checkmark).